# Can't read files inside native service app - Gear Fit 2

Tags: native, tizen

I have very strange issue on Gear Fit 2. I have native service in hybrid app (web app + native service in one package) and can't access to files. I got error message: Permission denied.

The code stops at getting folder attributes - line: if(stat(path,$st) == -1).

I don't know what is wrong. The code read files without problem when it is inside UI app but doesn't want to work in hybrid native service. Are there any constraints about reading files from service app on Gear Fit 2?

Of course I added privileges to tizen-manifes.xml.

http://tizen.org/privilege/mediastorage 
http://tizen.org/privilege/externalstorage

Code:

char *path;
storage_get_root_directory(STORAGE_TYPE_INTERNAL, &path); // works OK
// path contains now: /opt/usr/media

struct stat st;
if (stat(path, &st) == -1) { // STOP HERE, stat() returns -1
    return; // code enter here and ending
}

if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) {
... // not enter here

}

...

after calling

stat(path, &st); // it sets errno if fail

strerror(errno) returns message: **Permission denied.**

Comment: Share definition of "struct stat" .

Comment: Stat header here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html

Comment: I think there is deeper and global issue. Maybe native service can't access to file system on Gear Fit 2. However, it works if app is ordinary app (UI app). I asked that question to Samsung support and still wait for answer.

Comment: Ok, share your findings here.

Comment: So far I haven't got any help from Samsung support. Too bad.